# Создание нового столбца на основе значений другого столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два дата фрейма. Первый - df1:

```
         first_id second_id       price      
    0       59       22154       999.0      
    1       25       22154       999.0      
    2       25       22154       999.0      
    3       25       22154       999.0     
    4       25       22154       999.0  
    5       42       5037        800.0
```

и второй - df2:

```
      first_id  second_id  
    0        5     5037          
    1        4     5037           
    2        6     5037           
    3        3     5037           
    4        2     5037
    5       32     22154
```

Необходимо создать столбец *price* для df2 такой, чтобы значения *price* из df1 для *second_id* были идентичны для *second_id* из df2, т.е. на выходе получалось:

```
   first_id  second_id    price
0        5     5037        800.0  
1        4     5037        800.0   
2        6     5037        800.0   
3        3     5037        800.0   
4        2     5037        800.0
5       32     22154       999.0
```

т.е. новый *price* из df2 для *second_id* соответствовал тому же *price* для *second_id* из df1.
Немного криво получилось объяснить, но надеюсь, что поймете.

Пытался присоединить через *merge* по одному столбцу, однако столкнулся с проблемой, что если присоединяемый DataFrame по размерам больше, чем исходный, то последний в исходе в разы увеличивается. Хотя в принципе все по значениям вставлялось правильно.

```
df2.merge(df1[['second_id', 'price']], on='second_id')
```

P.S. в обоих дата фреймах сотни тысяч строк.

Comment: Приведите свой код с использованием pd.merge

Comment: `df2.merge(df1, on="second_id", how="left")` не дает нужного результата?

Comment: забыл указать, что в df1 есть еще столбцы, которые присоединять не нужно.

Comment: ну в моем ответе можете просто убрать ненужные столбцы из результирующего фрейма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При

```
df1:
   first_id  second_id  price
0        59      22154  999.0
1        25      22154  999.0
2        25      22154  999.0
3        25      22154  999.0
4        25      22154  999.0
5        42       5037  800.0

df2:
   first_id  second_id
0         5       5037
1         4       5037
2         6       5037
3         3       5037
4         2       5037
5        32      22154
```

```
res = df2.merge(df1[df1.columns[1:]].drop_duplicates("second_id"), on="second_id", how="left")
```

res будет:

```
   first_id  second_id  price
0         5       5037  800.0
1         4       5037  800.0
2         6       5037  800.0
3         3       5037  800.0
4         2       5037  800.0
5        32      22154  999.0
```